# Anime.Js Seek function not reversing in React

Tags: reactjs, animation, anime.js

I'm trying to make an animation that transitions as you scroll. I need it to reverse while scrolling up. I know this is possible ([here's an example](https://codepen.io/gaougalos/pen/bJXYZa)) but I can't get a similar behavior to work in React.

I made this demo as a way to simplify my issue (based on what's in [AnimeJs's docs](https://animejs.com/documentation/#seekAnim)):

```
const me = useRef();
const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(0);

const zoomies = anime({
  targets: me.current,
  translateY: "80vh",
  autoplay: false
});

useEffect(() => {
  zoomies.seek(zoomies.duration * (zoom / 100));
}, [zoom, zoomies]);
```

It's pretty simple, you can see it in action here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/animejs-react-seeking-wk09q

As you can see it only goes forward and not relative to slider. It also never reverses. I"m not sure what's going on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my animation, you can see a working version here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/animejs-react-seeking-h8y6m

The biggest change is that I moved the animation declaration into a `useState` hook. What I think was happening was the animation was being recreated on every tick so there was no way for it to reverse. But once React knew about it between re-renders it just started working.

If this is wrong or in any way inaccurate someone please correct me!